# Inserting Open Graph tags via custom module and block

Tags: template, module, custom-block, open-graph

**I'm using Magento EE 1.6**

When I use a custom block class to display some tags inside my `<head>`, block won't display. But if I use the `"page/html"` type, everything is fine... I need my custom class to add some features to the block (activation, getting image url etc).

Please help me to understand what I missed. Here is what I've done so far :

app/etc/modules/Wbx_Social.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Wbx_Social>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Wbx_Social>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Wbx/Social/etc/config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Wbx_Social>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Wbx_Social>
    </modules>
    <global>
        [...]
        <blocks>
            <wbx_social>
                <class>Wbx_Social_Block</class>
            </wbx_social>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <wbx_social>
                    <file>wbx_social.xml</file>
                </wbx_social>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Wbx/Social/Block/Opengraph.php :

```
class Wbx_Social_Block_Opengraph extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function isActive()
    {
        return true; // Will be replaced with store config value
    }

    /* And other useful functions */

}
```

app/design/frontend/responsive/default/layout/wbx_social.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="wbx_social/opengraph" name="opengraph" as="opengraph" template="social/opengraph.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

And finally the template : app/design/frontend/responsive/default/template/social/opengraph.phtml :

```
<?php /* @var $this Wbx_Social_Block_Opengraph */ ?>
<?php if ($this->isActive()) : ?>
    <meta property="fb:app_id"       content="an id"/>
    <meta property="og:type"         content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name"    content="a name"/>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Just in case, I didn't forget the `Wbx_Social_Helper_Data` empty helper.

In `wbx_social.xml`, when I try changing the block class for `type="core/template"` or `type="page/html"` (for example), the block is correctly displayed (without any access of custom functions of course)

I really need a hint, it's been several hours I'm tearing out...

Comment: anything in var/log folder?

Comment: Logs enabled, nothing in there. I hoped there would be some "class not found" warnings, but no :(

Comment: By any chance, do you have a `_toHtml()` method in your block? If yes, post it in the question. If no, then try to add something in the template outside the if statement and see if it prints.

Comment: No `_toHtml()` method.
I already tried printing something outside the if statement, and it's only working when this is **not** `type="wbx_social/opengraph"`.
So I think the problem is whether in config (blocks declaration) or layout config (bad type ?)

Comment: Change the module alias to "wbxsocial" everywhere instead of "wbx_social" as a last resort?

Comment: Tried already... And this was not the problem. I found the solution as I'll describe in my own answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out the origin of the problem.
The problem was indeed from my block `Wbx_Social_Block_Opengraph` that implemented a `getUrl()` method. Big mistake ! `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` (an ancestor of my block) has already a `getUrl()` method but with a different signature.
My real big question is : why the heck didn't I get any error / warning ?? It would have saved so much time...

Anyway, I changed my own method for `getOgUrl()` and VOILA ! My tags are displayed as I wanted....

Thanks a lot for your suggestions, folks !

Comment: May be you need to enable E_STRICT error level to see such type of errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are several block types in Magento. See app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\

One of them is "list". It gets all children and just output them one by one. The `content` block works like this.

But most of blocks have type "template". It means they have some .phtml templates associated and render them. For example, your block has such type.

To add some block in the head ( type="template" ), you have to edit the head.phtml file and call the child block using `$this->getChildHtml('opengraph')`

Comment: The `head.phtml` already has this : `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>`, meaning that all sorted children are displayed. I checked all `head`'s children, and my opengraph block isn't part of them. 

If I change the type for a native one (core/template, page/html...), my block appears in `head`'s sorted children.
Long story short : `echo $this->getChildHtml('opengraph')` has no effect as long as the block declaration is `type="wbx_social/opengraph"`